# r code giving error coerce type 'S4' to vector of type double

Tags: r, sparkr

I am new to r code so getting some issue here is the code

```
library(sparkr)
library(arulesViz)

test1 <- "select t.result from usertest l join userlab t on t.uid=l.uid where t.result is not null"
test2 <- "select t.result from usertest2 l join userlab2 t on t.uid=l.uid where t.result is not null"

tq <- sql(test1)
tm <- sql(test2)

tqn <- as.numeric(tq)
tmn <- as.numeric(tm)

wilconx.text(t1n, tmn, paired=FALSE, correct=FALSE)
```

error message: cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector type 'double'

please guide.